# Creating a dropdown in MVC3 C# with ViewModel and easy model binding on POST back.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, drop-down-menu, viewmodel

I have this problem where i want to make 7 dropdowns for each day of the week.
In each one of those dropdowns i wish to add the same data.

My ViewModel:

```
public class WeekDienstCreateViewModel
{
    public WeekDienst weekDienst {get; set;}
    public List<DienstPerWeekDienst> diensten { get; set; }

    public WeekDienstCreateViewModel() { }
}
```

My Create Method in Controller:
As u can see I add everything allready except DienstId which is want to add with my dropdowns.

```
 public ActionResult Create(int id)
        {
            WeekDienst wd = _service.FindWeekDienst(id);
            WeekDienstCreateViewModel vm = new WeekDienstCreateViewModel();

            vm.diensten = new List<DienstPerWeekDienst>();
            vm.weekDienst = wd;

            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
            {
                DienstPerWeekDienst dpwd = new DienstPerWeekDienst();
                dpwd.volgnummer = i;
                dpwd.WeekDienstId = wd.Id;

                vm.diensten.Add(dpwd);
            }
            ViewBag.Diensten = _service.DienstenList(wd.AfdelingId);

            return View(vm);
        }
```

Classes:

```
 public class DienstPerWeekDienst
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int WeekDienstId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int DienstId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(1, 7)]
        public int volgnummer { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("WeekDienstId")]
        public virtual WeekDienst WeekDienst { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DienstId")]
        public virtual Dienst Dienst { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<WeekDienst> WeekDiensten { get; set; }
    }

 public class WeekDienst
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int AfdelingId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} cannot exceed {1} characters.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}$", ErrorMessage = "Verplicht 5 cijfers lang.")]
        public string code { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Template")]
        public bool template { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AfdelingId")]
        public virtual Afdeling Afdeling { get; set; }
    }
```

And in my view i wish to create 7 dropdowns where i put in all my "Diensten" (class Dienst, fk in DienstPerWeekDienst). When I choose 1 i wish to add the "DienstId" into the "DienstPerWeekDienst" class.

So in my View i got this:

```
            @foreach (var day in Model.diensten)                 
             {   
                  var currentDay=day;
                  @Html.DropDownListFor(currentDropDown=>currentDay, new SelectList(ViewBag.Diensten, "Value", "Text"))                 
             }
```

I Wish to postback the chosen "Diensten" and create the "WeekDienst" but now i am just posting a null "DienstPerDienstWeekCreateViewModel". How am I able to fix this?

Thanks in Advance

FIX (Thanks to Siva Gopal)

I fixed this by doing:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < @Model.diensten.Count; i++)
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => (m.diensten[i].volgnummer))
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => (m.diensten[i].WeekDienstId))
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m=> (m.diensten[i].DienstId), new SelectList(ViewBag.Diensten, "Value", "Text"))
                }
```

Comment: Please let me know, if you still face problems after having a look at the solution i gave below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using

```
@foreach (var day in Model.diensten)                 
 {   
      var currentDay=day;              
      @Html.DropDownListFor(currentDropDown=>currentDay, new SelectList(ViewBag.Diensten, "PropertyName_Holding_Value", "PropertyName_Holding_DisplayText"), new { })                 
 }  //This uses the Lambda Expression. Your dropdown Name/Id would be 1,2,3 etc. based on currentDay value.
```

OR

```
@foreach (var day in Model.diensten)                 
 {   
      var currentDay=day;
      var dropdownName=string.Format("diensten[{0}]",day-1); //If you want to model bind the selected dropdown value to input entity in POST request. The final dropdownName format should match the hierarchy of the property inside input entity/object. Even without this name formation, you can still POST the selected value back using Jquery/Javascript.
      @Html.DropDownList(dropdownName, new SelectList(ViewBag.Diensten, "PropertyName_Holding_Value", "PropertyName_Holding_DisplayText"), new {})                 
 }  //
```

**Note for Value Post back/model bind on full Page submit:** 
To be able to model bind/POST back values to the server, the html element names corresponding to the properties should be rendered as follows: Suppose if you display Employee.Department.Name, then name of textbox, displaying the Department Name in View should match Department_ReferenceName_Inside_Employee.Name for model binding.

**Model:**
    public class Employee
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            public Department EmpDepartment { get; set; }
            public List SubOrdinates { get; set; }
        }
        public class Department
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            //Prepare the model and send it to the view
            Employee emp = new Employee { EmpDepartment = new Department { Name = "IT" } };
            emp.SubOrdinates = new List<Employee> { new Employee { Name = "Emp1" }, new Employee { Name = "Emp2" } };
            return View(emp);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Employee emp)
        { //Put a break-point here and see how the modified values in view are flowing into emp..
            return View(emp); 
        }
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**View:**

```
@model MvcApplication.Models.Employee
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmpDepartment.Name)
    @Html.LabelForModel("SubOrdinates :")
    for (int i = 0; i < @Model.SubOrdinates.Count; i++)
    {
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => (m.SubOrdinates[i].Name))
    }
<input type="submit" name="name" value="Submit" />    }
```

**ViewSource/PageSource:**
The above text box syntax will be rendered as :

```
<input id="EmpDepartment_Name" name="EmpDepartment.Name" type="text" value="IT" />    <!--See above html : name=EmpDepartment.Name --> 
<label for="">SubOrdinates :</label>  
<input id="SubOrdinates_0__Name" name="SubOrdinates[0].Name" type="text" value="Emp1" />  
<input id="SubOrdinates_1__Name" name="SubOrdinates[1].Name" type="text" value="Emp2" />  <!--See above html for how collection item Name(s) are being renderd by view engine-->     
<input type="submit" name="name" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Thanks i can display my "Diensten" now but i want to post the ViewModel back now with the list of 7 "DienstPerWeekDienst". Now i am only returning an empty viewmodel.

Comment: @user1242203: Are you using <input type="submit" .../> button on your page for POSTing or using any script(jquery/AJAX etc.) based posting ? If you are using 'submit' button POST then please go though my comments in the second code snippet once again, you will come to know what needs to be done to POST values back to server. Also please don't forget to upvote & mark as answer if you find my answer(s) helpful to you :) .

Comment: I understand what to do but not how to do it. I would love to up vote you but I just started using this website (I was out of options ;)) I will up vote u when I get 15 reputation!

Comment: Well i'm still stuck :p. I am using the very first snippet to make the dropdown. so now i wish to fill in the ViewModel. But I have no idea how to do this. Because the ViewModel contains a list. And i need to fill that with 7 "DienstPerDienstWeek" objects. So I would really like to see how i can do this in my View. Because now he is just returning a null when i do a post.

Comment: @Rmon: To get an idea, i suggest you go with a sample MVC app with the code i posted to understand and then gradually move towards your specific problem.

Comment: I'm working on it, it is looking good so far i'm getting a ViewModel back which isn't null!

Comment: Thanks for the help! U solved my problem. I will not forget this and i will upvote u for this. Anything else i can do in return?

Comment: Nothing but remember the solution, since you may need to help your team many times in future :), if they are new to asp.net MVC since the problem has recurrance(s). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (var day in Model.diensten)
{
   var currentDay = day;
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => currentDay, new SelectList(ViewBag.Diensten, "Value", "Text"), new { @id = "DienstList" })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MvcApplication1.Models.Country> cntry = db.Countries.ToList();
SelectListItem sss = new SelectListItem();
List<SelectListItem> sltst = new List<SelectListItem>();
sss.Text = "Select";
sss.Value = "0";
sltst.Add(sss);
foreach (MvcApplication1.Models.Country s in cntry){
SelectListItem s1 = new SelectListItem();
s1.Text = s.Country1;
s1.Value = Convert.ToString(s.Id);
sltst.Add(s1);}
@Html.DropDownList("country", sltst, new { @id = "country" })
```