# ViewModel is null upon form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

What i am trying to do is create a SubCategory object. In order to do so i have made a viewmodel that will supply my view with the nescesarry data (including a category object that the subcategory will be bound to.)

when i post my form the viewmodel is returned to my controller but all the properties of my subcategory and my selected value from a dropdownlist is null.

what am i doing wrong? :S

view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SkyLearn.Areas.Categories.Models.CategoryViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Create
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>SubCategory</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.subcategory.Title) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.subcategory.Title)%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.subcategory.Title)%>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.subcategory.Icon)%>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="file" name="icon" id="icon"/>
        </div>

        <%: Html.DropDownListFor(selectedcategory => Model.selectedCategory, Model.categories) %>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.subcategory.Description)%>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.subcategory.Description)%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.subcategory.Description)%>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<div>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="SideContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "administrator")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(CategoryViewModel viewmodel, HttpPostedFileBase Icon)
        {
            SubCategory subcategory = viewmodel.subcategory;

            subcategory.Category = categorycontroller.getCategoryByName(viewmodel.selectedCategory);

            if (Icon != null && Icon.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // extract only the filename
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(Icon.FileName);
                // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("../../Content/icons/"), fileName);
                Icon.SaveAs(path);
                subcategory.Icon = fileName;
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.subcategories.Add(subcategory);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
            }

            return View(subcategory);
        }
```

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SkyLearn.Areas.Categories.Models
{
    public class CategoryViewModel
    {
        public List<SelectListItem> categories;
        public SubCategory subcategory;
        public string selectedCategory;

        public CategoryViewModel()
        {
            categories = new List<SelectListItem>();
            subcategory = new SubCategory();
            selectedCategory = "";
        }
    }
}
```

the viewmodel contains a list of categories that the subcategory im trying to create can be bound to. it also contains a subcategory object i can use to create the subcategory from. and the last property is a string i want to use for binding the choice in the dropdownlist.

Comment: May be the post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513385/creating-a-dropdown-in-mvc3-c-sharp-with-viewmodel-and-easy-model-binding-on-pos/9513747#9513747 , help you get with the default model binding.

Comment: I already read most of the post on the topic. I might be wrong but i think i already have input fields (html.editorfor) and using the correct names in order to bind it. Im kinda new to mvc so i might be completely wrong

Comment: Once again i must shamefully admit that i forgot something as simple as adding Get; Set; it all works now. sigh. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net MVC3's SelectListItem doesn't behave how you'd expect. Also, try Html.DropDownListFor() rather than Html.EditorFor() to make your dropdown list.

**In the ViewModel:**

```
public IList<string> PossibleValues {get; set;}
public string SelectedValue {get; set;}
```

Load the values into PossibleValues in your ViewModel's constructor.

**In the View:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, new SelectList(Model.PossibleValues))
```

This will autogenerate your dropdown list and bind it to your model. You can pass default values and other customizations into this Html helper function too, if you want.

**Saving Other Values**
You can save other values, values which the user shouldn't have the option to edit but which aren't mission-critical if the user does edit, with

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RememberThisValue);
```

Remember, this value is hidden from display but can still be edited on the DOM and posted with whatever the user wants. Make sure you protect yourself from malicious value injection by checking POST'd hidden values.

Store everything important on the server-side, pass a hash/private key in to the user through your model, and implement a static session dictionary to store these small bits of information.

Comment: I am using the Html.DropDownListFor.
also the only source the dropdownlist helper accepts is selectItem list. so it will cause an error to do that. is there any other way to bind the rest of my properties to the model?

Comment: I managed to get the selectedvalue to be posted on submit thanks to your reply. It is still a mystery to me how i can get the rest of my viewmodel populated with the right values from the view. any comments on that?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I fixed my example and added an answer about the rest of your values.