# Can't insert the selected value of CheckBox to database, it never hits my post submitData method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

- My controller I cant seem to bind the `submitdata` method to check box with `id=answerA`. At the moment I just want to insert one value the later will adjust accommodate 3 answer options:

  ```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult SubmitData(QuestionnareModels models)
  {
      using (QUESTIONNAREDataContext db = new QUESTIONNAREDataContext())
      {
          SubmitTable answerSubmit = new SubmitTable()
          {
              SubmitID = 1,
              CorrectAnswer = models.AnswerA
          };
          db.SubmitTables.InsertOnSubmit(answerSubmit);
          db.SubmitChanges();
      }
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }`
  ```
- My view, where I render my check boxes from a `linq database`:

  ```
  <div class="container">
      <h2><mark>Questionnare system</mark></h2>
      @using (Html.BeginForm("uploadAnswer"))
      {
          foreach (var questionType in Model)
          {
              @questionType.Question
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <input type="checkBox" id="AnswerA" />
              @questionType.AnswerA
              <br />
              <input type="checkBox" id="AnswerB" />
              @questionType.AnswerB
              <br />
              <input type="checkBox" id="AnswerC" />
              @questionType.Answerc
              <br/>
              <br/>
          }
          <br />
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submitDataButton">Submit</button>
      }
   </div>
  ```

Comment: Lean to use strongly types helpers and render the collection in a `for` loop. This code is creating duplicate `id` (invalid html) and `name` attributes which wont post back to a collection. You need to post your `QuestionnareModels`

Comment: And why are you using `Html.BeginForm("uploadAnswer")` which post back to `uploadAnswer()` method? and can a user select multiple answers or just one (in which case it should be radio buttons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems including invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes), missing `name` attributes (nothing in the form will post back), incorrect use of checkboxes (unchecked checkboxes do not post back so there is no way of knowing which answer belongs with which question), posting back to the wrong method and allowing multiple answers for the same question. You need to create view models that represent what you want to display and edit

View models

```
public class QuestionVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public int SelectedAnswer { get; set; }
  public List<AnswerVM> AnswerList { get; set; }
}
public class AnswerVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }   
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  List<QuestionVM> model = new QuestionVM();
  // populate your questions and the possible answers for each question
  return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(List<QuestionVM> model)
{
  // The model now contains the ID of each question and the ID of its selected answer
}
```

View

```
@model List<QuestionVM>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ID)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Text)
    foreach(AnswerVM answer in Model[i].AnswerList)
    {
      string id = "answer" + answer.ID; 
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].SelectedAnswer, answer.ID, new { id = @id })
      <label for="@id">@answer.Text</label>
    }
  }
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Looking at you controller code, I suspect your database structure is wrong. You would need a table for `Questions` (ID, Text, etc), a table for `Answers` (ID, Text, QuestionID, etc) and  a table for users answers to questions (say) `UserQuestionaires` (UserID, QuestionID, AnswerID, etc)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your problem, I can see the 'form' action in html is "uploadAnswer" where as you posted the action method code for "SubmitData".

So what happens if you change "uploadAnswer" in Html.BeginForm("uploadAnswer") to Html.BeginForm("SubmitData"), are you able to hit the controller ?

Also for proper model binding, the name of html element and the property name of model should be same. So change html to: `<input type="checkBox" name="AnswerA" id="AnswerA" />` (Assuming "AnswerA" is a property of your Questionaire model.

If you want to model bind to a collection, please take a look at [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513385/creating-a-dropdown-in-mvc3-c-sharp-with-viewmodel-and-easy-model-binding-on-pos/9513747#9513747).

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
    <h2><mark>Questionnare system</mark></h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitData"))
    {
        foreach (var questionType in Model)
        {
            @questionType.Question
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <input type="checkBox" name="AnswerA" />
            @questionType.AnswerA
            <br />
            <input type="checkBox" name="AnswerB" />
            @questionType.AnswerB
            <br />
            <input type="checkBox" name="AnswerC" />
            @questionType.Answerc
            <br/>
            <br/>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submitDataButton">Submit</button>
        }
        <br />

    }
 </div>
```

Two issue

1. BeginForm should have method or action you have specificed in Controller
2. Submit button must be inside form.
3. You should not use ID. You have to use name.